# ZipArchive is missing, how include it in DockerFile?

Tags: php, dockerfile, phpexcel, php-ziparchive

I have this error :

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'ZipArchive' not found in
> **/var/www/html/excel/phpExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php** on
> line **227**

because I have to move my site from one server to a new one (with DockerFile...)

I'm using PHPExcel, and like we can see in the error, ZipArchive is missing.

Do you know how can I include it below in my DockerFile please ?

```
FROM registry.xe.ulb.be:5000/global-okd/php/5.6.40-apache-cas:latest

LABEL maintainer="JBM<jJBM@nothing.be> && Developper"

USER root

# Add here your PHP ext
# Ex : RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

The following extensions are [required](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/install.txt) prior to using PHPExcel:

- zip
- xml
- gd

Check if these extensions installed:

- Using **command line**

```
php -m
```

- Using **php code**:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

If they are not installed, you just need to install the required extensions.
Make sure to have `libzip-dev` package at runtime, since `zip` extension requires it.

```
# Install required dependency
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev

# Configure and install gd extension
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Install zip and zml
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip xml
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I'm a newbie with Docker File.  This is the message I got : STEP 4: RUN docker-php-ext-install PHPExcel
error: /usr/src/php/ext/PHPExcel does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] ext-name [ext-name ...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install -j5 gd mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop

if custom ./configure arguments are necessary, see docker-

Comment: Thank you, this is what I added : # Ex : RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysql
#Added by David Dubois for phpexcel extenion
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
  #End David Dubois

Comment: Hey, I've added some commands, because other than `zip` extensions, it requires `gd` and `xml` ext. But before that, can you confirm if these extensions available or not?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't have access to the server, How can I know it please ?  Thank you again

Comment: You can try to add the latest commands. I've also added how to check if php webserver has certain extensions.

Comment: Thank you very much, the error is different now : <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /var/www/htmlevaluation/evaluation_par_mds/mds_-etu_ du 04-02-2019 au 04-03-2019 (Hospitalier NEW).xlsx.' in /var/www/html/excel/phpExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:399.  Before not found, now not could not close

Comment: From the exception thrown, it seems like PHPExcel is unable to write to the specified file or write to the directory that will contain the file. It's probably a permission problem, make sure if the script has access to the directory where the file should be written to. This is what I found, it might be caused be other problems listed [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/795/how-to-solve-phpexcel-fatal-error-uncaught-exception-phpexcel-writer-exception-with-message-could-not-close-zip).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242453/discussion-between-ncxnav-and-david-dubois).

Comment: Did you solve it yet?